# Why Do We Still Practice Pidyon Haben?

Tags: minhag, pidyon-haben

On p. 967 of "The Torah a Modern Commentary" (Plaut, revised edition) it is written, "...all of Israel's first born sons belong to G-d (Num. 8:13-17).  Because **G-d accepts the Levites as substitutes**, they are set aside in a special way."

My question is, if G-d accepted the Levites in place of the male first born, then why do we need to redeem our male first born children today through the practice of [Pidyon Haben?](https://reformjudaism.org/beliefs-practices/lifecycle-rituals/birth-rituals/what-pidyon-haben)

[Sefaria Numbers 8:13-17](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.8.12-17?lang=bi&aliyot=0)

> 13 וְהַֽעֲמַדְתָּ֙ אֶת־הַלְוִיִּ֔ם לִפְנֵ֥י אַהֲרֹ֖ן וְלִפְנֵ֣י
> בָנָ֑יו וְהֵנַפְתָּ֥ אֹתָ֛ם תְּנוּפָ֖ה לַֽיהֹוָֽה׃
>
> You shall place the Levites in attendance upon Aaron and his sons, and
> designate them as an elevation offering to the LORD.
>
> 14 וְהִבְדַּלְתָּ֙ אֶת־הַלְוִיִּ֔ם מִתּ֖וֹךְ בְּנֵ֣י יִשְׂרָאֵ֑ל
> וְהָ֥יוּ לִ֖י הַלְוִיִּֽם׃
>
> Thus you shall set the Levites apart from the Israelites, and the
> Levites shall be Mine.
>
> 15 וְאַֽחֲרֵי־כֵן֙ יָבֹ֣אוּ הַלְוִיִּ֔ם לַעֲבֹ֖ד אֶת־אֹ֣הֶל מוֹעֵ֑ד
> וְטִֽהַרְתָּ֣ אֹתָ֔ם וְהֵנַפְתָּ֥ אֹתָ֖ם תְּנוּפָֽה׃
>
> Thereafter the Levites shall be qualified for the service of the Tent
> of Meeting, once you have cleansed them and designated them as an
> elevation offering.
>
> 16 כִּי֩ נְתֻנִ֨ים נְתֻנִ֥ים הֵ֙מָּה֙ לִ֔י מִתּ֖וֹךְ בְּנֵ֣י
> יִשְׂרָאֵ֑ל תַּ֩חַת֩ פִּטְרַ֨ת כׇּל־רֶ֜חֶם בְּכ֥וֹר כֹּל֙ מִבְּנֵ֣י
> יִשְׂרָאֵ֔ל לָקַ֥חְתִּי אֹתָ֖ם לִֽי׃
>
> For they are formally assigned to Me from among the Israelites: I have
> taken them for Myself in place of all the first issue of the womb, of
> all the first-born of the Israelites.
>
> 17 כִּ֣י לִ֤י כׇל־בְּכוֹר֙ בִּבְנֵ֣י יִשְׂרָאֵ֔ל בָּאָדָ֖ם
> וּבַבְּהֵמָ֑ה בְּי֗וֹם הַכֹּתִ֤י כׇל־בְּכוֹר֙ בְּאֶ֣רֶץ מִצְרַ֔יִם
> הִקְדַּ֥שְׁתִּי אֹתָ֖ם לִֽי׃
>
> For every first-born among the Israelites, man as well as beast, is
> Mine; I consecrated them to Myself at the time that I smote every
> first-born in the land of Egypt.

Comment: Levites are exempt from Pidyon Haben

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Levite-counts-for-you was a one-time deal in the desert as they solidified the tribal system and consecrated the Levites. (Earlier in the Book of Numbers.) One particular firstborn at the time might not need *pidyon haben* because a Levite peer of his that day was consecrated. If you couldn't find a Levite peer who was becoming holy that day, you paid five shekels.

The Levites themselves, by the way, are exempted from the five shekels in perpetuity. (Even if mom was a Levite, actually.)

For future generations, though, the Levites are already as holy as they're going to be, so the (non-Levite) firstborn are stuck paying five shekels. See [Numbers 18:15](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.18.15?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), a few chapters later, that makes clear that future generations will have to pay the five shekels.